# In regards to translating another user's questions

Tags: discussion, site-policies

[https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327362/Помогите-исправить-ошибку-срочноЯне-разбираюсь-в-кодах?noredirect=1#comment466683_327362](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327362/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85?noredirect=1#comment466683_327362)

The question has been deleted by now, but I can see in my inbox the beginning of a comment that goes:

> @User1337 We don't translate user's posts. Too much meaning can get lost in auto-transla...

Now, I do suspect that the question was removed because it was in russian, and possibly because my edit wasn't approved based on what the comment referred to.

The question is thus whether a translation edit is valid when the translator is a native/fluent speaker - which I am in the given case - or alternatively whether I ought to recommend deletion rather than bothering translating in the first place despite being able to accurately do so.